# How to highlight a row in pandas df if it is in another df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to highlight any row in one column in my dataframe if it exists in another.
I have tried:

```
apics_tonal_features.style.apply(lambda x: ["background: red" if v.isin(blasi_final_features['x']) else "" for v in x], axis = 1)
```

but since I am comparing strings, it gives me the error

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isin'
```

Here's a little bit of reproducible code for the data frames I am using

```
apics_tonal_features = pd.DataFrame({'Feature Name': ['Tone', 'Para-linguistic usages of clicks'],
                                'Feature ID': ['120', '108'],
                                 'Number of Languages': ['74', '64'],
                                 'Number of Variance': ['5', '4'],
                                'WALS Equivalent': ['WALS 13A', 'WALS 142A']})


blasi_final_features = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['order.of.subject.object.verb', 'Order.of.genitive.and.noun', 'Tone', 'Vowel nasalization']})
```

Comment: does `v in blasi_final_features['x']` work?

Comment: I don't think so. I just tried to change .isin() to simple v in blasi_final_features['x] and it didn't throw an error but also didn't highlight any rows

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the df.

```
   A   B  C   D
0  1   0  1   1
1  1   2  4   7
2  2   3  5   8
3  3   4  6   9
4  4   5  7  10
5  2  11  2   7
```

The output

```
     A       B       C       D
1: Red       0  1: Red  1: Red
1: Red  2: Red  4: Red  7: Red
2: Red  3: Red  5: Red       8
3: Red  4: Red       6       9
4: Red  5: Red  7: Red      10
2: Red      11  2: Red  7: Red
```

Explanation:

- A: all values exists in other columns
- B: values `0` and `11` are not present in other columns.
- C: value `6` is not present in other columns.
- D: values `8`, `9`, `10z are not present in other columns.

Code to achieve that

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "A": [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2], 
    "B": [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 11], 
    "C": [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2], 
    "D": [1, 7, 8, 9, 10, 7]
})

df = df.apply(
    lambda x: [f"{elem}: Red" if 
        any([elem in df[column].tolist() for column in if column != x.name]) 
    else elem for elem in x], axis=0)
```